# Why gnuplot plot don't plot straight lines?

Tags: gnuplot

I was trying to plot a regression line with gnuplot, but instead to plot a straight line plot a line full of bend.I printed it in png format.Here a pic.

[image]

Comment: I think the curve is an optical illusion - those look like straight lines to me.  By having the data points on the curve there, it can give that optical illusion.

Comment: So, how can I  make it less serrated? I have to increase resolution? And how can I increase resolution in a simple way without having to change the dimension of lines dots and index?

Comment: Use a `size` parameter with `set term`.

Comment: In this way I have to change all the dimensions of dots lines and index. I tried with 'set terminal  png size 1024,768'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the original question asks about why it's curved (and not about how to 'reduce the low-resolution segregation-ness' which is now being asked in comments):

The lines aren't actually curved. It's an optical illusion as a result of the  data points being around the line, close enough to mess with your perception of the actual state of the line - it's really actually straight.

An example of this is seen in the U&L Meta post on the Community Promotion Ads - [this post on the ad list](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3322/5807) shows how the lines are perceived as curved, when they're really actually straight.

Comment: Off-topic, but slightly related: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3322/70524

Comment: @muru PERFECT example of such an optical illusion.